# Laravel : How can i get old and new value by updateOrCreate

Tags: laravel

I want update or create in data base 
but i want get the old value and updated value because i want to compare between these two value

**for example**

this item in table user

```
name = Alex and Order = 10
```

so now i want update this person by

```
name = Alex and Order = 8
```

Now After updating or creating if not exist

just for update i want get

```
Old order 10 | And new Order 8
```

I want compare between these order

i have tryin **getChange()** and **getOriginal()** but two the function give me just the new value.

Please Help

Comment: You can always use the ID of the user table which is unique and update/create based on it. I guess you have an auto-incremented ID.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the old value using `getOriginal` if you have the object already loaded.

For example  :

```
$user = User::find(1);

$user->first_name = 'newname';

// Dumps `oldname`
dd($user->getOriginal('first_name'));
$user->save();
```

However in case of `updateOrCreate`, you just have the data. I am not sure about a way to do it using `updateOrCreate` but you can do simply do :

```
$user = User::where('name', 'Alex')->first();
$newOrder = 10;

if($user){
    $oldOrder = $user->getOriginal('order');
    $user->order = $newOrder;
    $user->save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the name unique in the table? Because if it is not you will have updates on multiple rows with the same data.

So the best approach is to use the unique column which is probably the ID.

```
User::updateOrCreate(
    [ 'id' => $request->get('id') ], // if the $id is null, it will create new row
    [ 'name' => $request->get('name'), 'order' => $request->get('order') ]
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution

```
            $model = Trend::where('name', $trend->name)->first();

        if ($model) {
            $model->old_order = $model->getOriginal('order');
            $model->order = $key + 1;
            $model->save();
        } else {
            Trend::where('order', $key + 1)->delete();
            $new = new Trend();
            $new->name = $trend->name;
            $new->old_order = $key + 1;
            $new->order = $key + 1;
            $new->tweet_volume = $trend->tweet_volume;
            $new->save();
        }
```